# Changing text element font size using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, font

I need my script to change the font size of a text element if the string is too long to fit in the title section of the map.

I've looked into it using ArcPy, but haven't had any luck.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
elmWidth = 4.0
elmText = '<dyn type="document" property="title"/>'
elm = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "MapTitle")[0]
x = 100
elm.text = '<FNT name="Arial" size="' + str(x) + '">' + elmText + '</FNT>'
while elm.elementWidth > float(elmWidth):
    elm.text = '<FNT name="Arial" size="' + str(x) + '">' + elmText + '</FNT>'
    x = x - 1
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
del mxd
```

Source: (Example 3)
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000000m000000.htm